# Replace Last Character of String

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I want to replace the last character in a string with a word.

Eg, 'Flight 12345 A' and I want it to look like 'Flight 12345 Auckland'
The last character can also be W, C, D, Q which stand for different city names.

How can I go about achieving this with js / jQuery??

Thanks heaps in advance!

Comment: Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace. Then give it a try, and come back with your code if you have any problems.

Comment: use string.replaceAt() , method passing string length-1 as parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a map of the different city names and then do the replacement by passing a function as callback to the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function :

```
var airports = {
     A: 'Auckland',
     C: 'City2'
     ...
};
var str2 = str.replace(/\w$/, function(l) { return airports[l] });
```

Comment: One last thing I forgot, the user can also select the option 'To Be Advised' if they don't know the address, Can I bypass this element if this is the case by adding something similar to   if ($(this) != 'To Be Advised'){

Comment: @Jamesil There are many ways to do this, [for example this one](http://jsfiddle.net/tu3J4/).